# Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. end of file reached (EOFError)

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd

I have an ECK setup https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/1.0-beta/k8s-overview.html. I am trying to add fluentd so k8 logs can be sent to elasticsearch to be viewed in kibana.

However when i look at the fluentd pod i can see the following errors. It looks like its having trouble connecting to Elasticsearch or finding it?

> 2020-07-02 15:47:54 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_es] Could not communicate to
> Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. end of file
> reached (EOFError) 2020-07-02 15:47:54 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_es]
> Remaining retry: 14. Retry to communicate after 2 second(s).

> 2020-07-02 15:47:58 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_es] Could not communicate to
> Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. end of file
> reached (EOFError) 2020-07-02 15:47:58 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_es]
> Remaining retry: 13. Retry to communicate after 4 second(s).

**elastic.yml**

```
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: es-gp2
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
reclaimPolicy: Delete
---
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: data-es
spec:
  version: 7.4.2
  spec:
    http:
      tls:
        certificate:
          secretName: es-cert
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 2
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: es-data
        annotations:
          volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: es-gp2
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: es-gp2
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
    config:
      node.master: true
      node.data: true
      node.ingest: true
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
      xpack.security.authc.realms:
        native:
          native1: 
            order: 1
---
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: data-kibana
spec:
  version: 7.4.2
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: data-es
```

**fluentd.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: elastic
  labels:
    app: fluentd
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluentd
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluentd
  namespace: elastic
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: elastic
  labels:
    app: fluentd
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fluentd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fluentd
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-elasticsearch
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "data-es-es-default.default"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
          - name: FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF
            value: disable
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

Im unsure about the **FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST** variable. The value i have set is `data-es-es-default.default`. Because i have a service called `data-es-es-default` and it's within the default namespace.

Ive setup fluentd and only fluentd using the following guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-elasticsearch-fluentd-and-kibana-efk-logging-stack-on-kubernetes#step-4-%E2%80%94-creating-the-fluentd-daemonset. An existing elasticsearch was already present in the kubernetes cluser which was setup using ECK elastic link above.

**data-es-es-default**:

Does not look like its exposed as a http service over 9200

[image]

**data-es-es-http**

It looks like i have second service exposed a http service over 9200, im not sure what the difference between these two are.

[image]

**Curl the es service from within the pod:**

```
curl -u elastic:mypassword https://data-es-es-http.default:9200 -k
{
  "name" : "data-es-es-default-1",
  "cluster_name" : "data-es",
  "cluster_uuid" : "vPWB0jbBT76Aq6Tbo7ta7w",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.4.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "2f90bbf7b93631e52bafb59b3b049cb44ec25e96",
    "build_date" : "2019-10-28T20:40:44.881551Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.2.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Your config looks good to me, and your `FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST` value is probably correct as is. Is your elasticsearch service exposed as an HTTP service over port 9200? Can we see that service config? And possibly the deployment that the service selects?

Comment: @IanGabes hey, please see my question ive added the elastic.yml we have.

Comment: and the services

Comment: I changed the host to `data-es-es-http.default` to test if it can communicate to that service but it looks like it can't. Same erors

Comment: I think that new service name is probably correct as well. It seems odd that your service has 0/TCP listed in the target column, but I am not super familiar with this UI. Is the Kibana instance running and working? I would be interested to see if your 2 nodes are present there. If not, can you do that curl again for `_cat/nodes`? You configs seem okay, there must be something we are missing. Is your cert there self signed? Maybe test with `FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY` set to `"false"`

Comment: yes i added the username pas password, added https infront of the host name and set ssl_verify to false and then it worked

Comment: but i dont know if thats right, atleast its working